# Pytorch: Visualize model while training

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

I am training a neural network by regression but it is predicting a constant value during testing. Which is why I want to visualize the weights of the neural network change during training and see the weights change dynamically in the `jupyter notebook`. 
Currently, my model looks like this:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.inp = nn.Linear(2, 40)
        self.act1 = nn.Tanh()
        self.h1 = nn.Linear(40, 40)
        self.act2 = nn.Tanh()
        self.h2 = nn.Linear(40, 2)
        self.act3 = nn.Tanh()
        #self.h3 = nn.Linear(20, 20)
        #self.act4=nn.Tanh()
        self.h4 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward_one_pt(self, x):
        out = self.inp(x)
        out = self.act1(out)
        out = self.h1(out)
        out = self.act2(out)
        out = self.h2(out)
        out = self.act3(out)
        #out = self.h3(out)
        #out = self.act4(out)
        out = self.h4(out)
        return out

    def forward(self, config):
        E = torch.zeros([config.shape[0], 1])
        for i in range(config.shape[0]):
            E[i] = self.forward_one_pt(config[i])
            # print("config[",i,"] = ",config[i],"E[",i,"] = ",E[i])
        return torch.sum(E, 0)
```

and my main function looks like this:

```py
def main()  :
    learning_rate = 0.5
    n_pts = 1000
    t_pts = 100
    epochs = 15

    coords,E = load_data(n_pts,t_pts)

    #generating my data to NN
    G = get_symm(coords,save,load_symmetry,symmtery_pickle_file,eeta1,eeta2,Rs,ex,lambdaa,zeta,boxl,Rc,pi,E,scale)
    net = Net()
    if(cuda_flag):
        net.cuda()
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    net_trained = train(save,text_output,epochs,n_pts,G,E,net,t_pts,optimizer,criterion,out,cuda_flag)
    test(save,n_pts,t_pts,G,E,net_trained,out,criterion,cuda_flag)

    torch.save(net,save_model)
```

any tutorials or answers would be helpful

Comment: Not directly answering your question but you could also have a look at this [Pytorch test suite](https://pypi.org/project/torchtest/) which provides an automatic check if your weights change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `model.state_dict()` to see if your weights are updating across epochs:

```
old_state_dict = {}
for key in model.state_dict():
    old_state_dict[key] = model.state_dict()[key].clone()

output = model(input)

new_state_dict = {}
for key in model.state_dict():
    new_state_dict[key] = model.state_dict()[key].clone()

for key in old_state_dict:
    if not (old_state_dict[key] == new_state_dict[key]).all():
        print('Diff in {}'.format(key))
    else:
        print('NO Diff in {}'.format(key))
```

On a side note, you can vectorize your forward function instead of looping over it. Following would do the same job as your original forward function but much faster:

```
def forward(self, config):
    out= self.forward_one_pt(config)
    return torch.sum(out, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think your suggestion to `forward` does the same thing as mine. I am training multiple configurations in `config` (denoted by `config[i]` ) and then adding their outputs to compare with the correct `Y` and calculate the loss.

Comment: all [`torch.nn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Linear) modules you are using in your forward function can work in parallel on multiple samples.  You can also compare the out of forward function in two cases and verify. Unless of course, i am missing something and each config[i] itself contains multiple samples.

Comment: each `config[i]` contains 2 parameters which is the input to the NN

Comment: which means, each `config[i]` is a single sample consisting of a vector of size 2, in that case we do not need to loop over each sample. Pytorch will automatically apply do the `forward` pass in parallel over the whole batch of samples.